# how to convert world lat and long coordinates to something ONE simulator understands?

Tags: coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, one-simulator

I have the coordinates of Manhattan in a `.wkt` file and an example of that file content is: `LINESTRING (40.619605 -73.9584046, 40.6205286 -73.9585793, 40.6206127 -73.9585952)`

ONE simulator does not recognize such coordinates to display the map of Manhattan and instead needs something that looks like this: `LINESTRING (4883.179 10736.259, 4924.922 10811.716)`

I'm not sure what format that is nor not sure what to search for in google. I need to know how to convert from `LINESTRING (40.619605 -73.9584046, ...` to something like `LINESTRING (4883.179 10736.259, 4924.922 10811.716)`

preferred language is python, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The format ONE uses is subset of the standard WKT format. See details in the [WKTReader](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/master/src/input/WKTReader.java) class and [ReadMe](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/wiki/README#movement-models).

The coordinates used in the WKT input files are in reference to the simulation world coordinates. You can open your source map file with a WKT editor (e.g., [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/)) and translate the coordinates so that they’re all positive and that could be enough.